# Need solution for the complex query matrix output in mariadb

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, pivot-table, cross-join

```
create table role (
  role varchar(20),
  id int
);

insert into role (role, id) values ('Friend', 1);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Son', 2);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Daughter', 3);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Father', 4);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Mother', 5);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Brother', 6);
insert into role (role, id) values ('Sister', 7);

create table person (
  persons varchar(20),
  personid int
);

insert into person (persons, personid) values ('James', 1);
insert into person (persons, personid) values ('Peter', 2);
insert into person (persons, personid) values ('Joseph', 3);
insert into person (persons, personid) values ('Jeni', 4);

create table role_person (
  roleid int,
  personid int
);

insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (2, 1);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (2, 2);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (4, 2);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (6, 2);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (6, 2);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (3, 4);
insert into role_person (roleid, personid) values (4, 3);
```

I want the final output as follows
[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29idB.png)

```
    persons  friend  son  daughter  father  mother  brother  sister
    James    -       Y    -         -       -       -        -
    Peter    -       Y    -         Y       -       Y        -
    Joseph   -       -    -         Y       -       -        -
    Jeni     -       -    Y         -       -       -        -
```

As the underlying database is Maria DB, I cannot use pivot function.
Please note that people can increase or decrease/
also, the role can increase tomorrow like grandfather, wife etc.

Not sure how to tackle this one in stored proc or query.

CAN WE USE XML DATA TYPE to handle dynamic query.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB? Prior to 10.2.1 or newer?

Comment: 10.2.1 is db version

Comment: See other questions tagged pivot-table.

Comment: pivot-table is not available for mariaDB

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select 
    p.persons,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 1) then 'Y' else '-' end as friend,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 2) then 'Y' else '-' end as son,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 3) then 'Y' else '-' end as daughter,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 4) then 'Y' else '-' end as father,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 5) then 'Y' else '-' end as mother,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 6) then 'Y' else '-' end as brother,
    case when 1 in (select 1 from role_person rp where rp.personid = p.personid and rp.roleid = 7) then 'Y' else '-' end as sister
  from person p;
```

Result:

```
persons  friend  son  daughter  father  mother  brother  sister
James    -       Y    -         -       -       -        -
Peter    -       Y    -         Y       -       Y        -
Joseph   -       -    -         Y       -       -        -
Jeni     -       -    Y         -       -       -        -
```

Comment: i do not know the list of roles before hand ie the problem, otherwise the solution is perfect

Comment: Ah... you need dynamic number of columns then. I don't know if you can do that in MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to retrieve a dynamic number of columns in MariaDB so far.

As far as I know this functionaly is only present in:

- Oracle (as "model").
- PostgreSQL (as "crosstab").
- SQL Server (as "pivot").

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using temporary table, altering the temporary for every field, and updating with correct parameter.